# Multiple url API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I want to fetch multiple url API, but while I am trying it's thrown an error '**Error: Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Promise]**'. Data displays in console because of testing, and it's how I wanted: 4 objects from 4 different URLs. But afterwards I wanted to add those objects to an empty array "allcities" what is already declared in the state. How to fix this code below?
BTW the error is while I want to change state after fetching url at line:

```
this.setState({
              allcities: [].concat(...data)
            });
```

Code below:

```
getWeatherAll = () => {
    const urls = [
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=658225&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`,
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=655195&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`,
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=650225&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`,
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=634964&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
    ];
    this.setState({
      temp: '',
      city: '',
      icon: '',
      description: '',
      time: '',
      wind: '',
      humidity: '',
      hours: [],
      cityId: ''

    }, Promise.all(
      urls.map(url =>
        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({
              allcities: [].concat(...data)
            });
          })
      ))
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad `setState` callback argument. `Promise.all` call returns a promise, not a function [as required].

It's enough to make this a function, something like that:

```
this.setState({
  temp: '',
  // ...
}, () => Promise.all(
  urls.map(url =>
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          allcities: [].concat(...data)
        });
      })
  ...
  ).then( () => console.log("done") )
)
```

### Problem with above

Every `setState` overwrites earlier state. It can be fixed by using function in `setState`:

```
this.setState( (prevState, props) => ({
  allcities: [...prevState.allcities, data]
}));
```

### Is this optimal?

Definitelly not. Data can arrive in different order (sometimes it matters) and we're calling `setState` multiple times while `Promise.all` can collect data for us natively (preserving original order) and we can `setState` only once:

```
this.setState({
  temp: '',
  // ...
}, () => Promise.all(
  urls.map(url =>
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        // console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
    )
  ).then( responses => {
    this.setState({
      allcities: responses
    });
    console.log("done")
  })
)
```

With requests defined in arrays (`.map` returns an array) you can improve readability during debugging:

```
const requestsLogged = urls.map(url =>
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log("fetch", res)
      return res // this is important
    })
);
Promise.all(requestsLogged).then(data => {
  console.log("all logged", data);
  //this.setState({
  //  allcities: data
  //});
});
```

Later you can shorten this to:

```
const requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kppcy1?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have two `then` on the same `fetch`, try something like:

```
Promise.all(
  urls.map(url =>
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
  )
).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.setState({
    allcities: [].concat(...data)
  });
})
```

You need to return a json from each of the request, and when all of them are done, you can use your `then` for Promise.all

If this doesn't work, please, try to create a jsfiddle or codepen where we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  allcities: [...state.allcities,data]
}));
```

and can you post what `data` looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is linked to the way you call `this.setState`.

As described in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) you may use a callback function as the second parameter.

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

In your case, you are using `Promise.all` as a callback which is not a function but a promise.

Replace

```
this.setState({...}, Promise.all(...));
```

By

```
this.setState({..});
Promise.all(...);
```

OR if you really need the callback

```
this.setState({..}, () => Promise.all(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved this problem by adding a new array and pushed 4 objects(json data) to the array and next I changed the state. It's working.

```
const requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
const newArr = [];
Promise.all(requests)
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        newArr.push(data);
        this.setState({
          allCities: [].concat(...newArr)
        });
      })
```

Comment: In this case this code (with passed `data`) should be run once ... and you don't need additional array - see my updated answer.

Comment: console.log(data) displays 4 objects(fetched from 4 urls). While I was trying your solution it threw me an error: "urls.map(...).then(....) is not a function." That's why, first I added these objects into array, now it's working.

Comment: that's it - 4 objects at once ... error could be from syntax, brackets matching ... see update and link